# change the background color of the title in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibackgroundcolor

I would like to change the background color of the title (only!) in UIButton, which contains title and image.

I can only see how to change to background color of the whole button, which is not what I want.

Any idea ?

Comment: And what is it supposed to be look like in the end?

Comment: Did you try set function? like this- **btnLogin.set...........**

Comment: use NSAttributedStrings

Comment: @Larme - Because of a different tint color, i can see a background color in the title different than the whole button, which is ugly. i just want to set the title's background to clear.

Comment: I don't truly know what you mean, but you can change only the titleLabel color by using `setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)` function on UIButton

Comment: @M.Wojcik - it will change the font color, not the background color of it.:(

Comment: Do you have a screenshot with your current button, and how it should like at the end? Because I find your issue unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is :

```
 btn.tintColor = UIColor.clear  //if we have different tint, which I had 
 btn.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set background color of titleLabel:

```
btn.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.
I also had to add btn.tintColor = UIColor.clear to remove the tint.

Answer (score -1):

To change button title color:

```
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.yourColor, for: .normal)
```

Comment: This will set the font color, not its background.