# How to change the background color of an UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to do something seamingly simple, change an UIButton's background for aesthetic purposes... but I cannot find a background property because every other button seems to be clear (Not have an explicit background colour )

```
func updateNewButton() {
    if newButton == true {
        let buttonFont = self.ButtonFont

        self.subscribeButton.SetAttributedTitle(title: StoreKit.sharedInstance.ButtonStateText, withFont: buttonFont, textColor: storeBackground, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change the background color of the title in UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985622/change-the-background-color-of-the-title-in-uibutton)

Answer (score 2):

To change the background color of your `UIButton`:

```
self.subscribeButton.backgroundColor = .yourDesiredColor
```

To change the background color of the **titleLabel** of your `UIButton`:

```
self.subscribeButton.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .yourDesiredColor
```